# Why does PrintWidget create Web_Map_as_JSON with explicit geometries for FeatureLayer features?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using a [print widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Print.html) to get exports of a map view. My view has a number of layers, one of them is a feature layer (in this case, showing US ZIP codes). When I look at the [ExportWebMap specification](https://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/create-web-apps/windows/exportwebmap-specification.htm) it looks like the syntax for feature layers, I should be able to simply provide object IDs for the features that ought to be displayed in the export. However, when I look at the JSON that's sent to the export service's execute task I see that my feature layer was instead treated as a collection of client side graphics - with full geometries listed instead of object IDs.

Aside from being slow this also causes the export operation to crash when my request payload gets too large.

Any insight as to why my FeatureLayer features might be getting serialized as client side graphics?

I'm using version 4.4 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed with API maintainers that this is expected behavior.

The PrintWidget that ships with the JS API **will** treat your feature layer features as client side graphics for purposes of exporting.

In my case, a single US ZIP Codes feature layer as low scale, this translated into requests on order of 20MB and larger being sent to the server. The recommended workaround in this case was to not use the provided PrintWidget and serialize the map manually as JSON, using feature IDs instead of geometries.